# Zend Controller Ajax call facing error

Tags: zend-framework, jquery

My Zend controller is like below:

```
 public function deleteAction()
    {
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
         $id = (int)$this->_request->getPost('id');
        $costs = new Application_Model_DbTable_Costs();
        if($costs->deleteCosts($id)){
            $this->view->success = "deleted";
        }

    }
```

And ajax call I ma using to post data is :

```
 $.ajax({
             dataType: 'json',
            url: 'index/delete',
            type: 'POST',
            data:id,
            success: function () {
             alert("success");
            },

            timeout: 13*60*1000,
            error: function(){
               console.log("Error");
            }

        });
```

And in my delete.phtml the code is like:

```
<?php 
    if($this->delete === true): 
        echo 'true';
    else:
        echo 'Sorry! we couldn\'t remove the source. Please try again.';
    endif;
?>
```

The response is returning the html.

Its my first project with Zend Framework.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your controller action is returning HTML, not JSON.

You should consider using the [AjaxContext](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.contextswitch.ajaxcontext) action helper

```
public function init()
{
    $this->_helper->ajaxContext->addActionContext('delete', 'json')
                               ->initContext();
}

public function deleteAction()
{
    $id = (int)$this->_request->getPost('id');
    $costs = new Application_Model_DbTable_Costs();
    try {
        $costs->deleteCosts($id));
        $this->view->success = "deleted";
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $this->view->error = $ex->getMessage();
    }    
}
```

The only other thing you need to do here is supply a `format` parameter of `json` in the AJAX request, eg

```
$.post('index/delete', { "id": id, "format": "json" }, function(data) {
    if (data.error) alert("Error: " + data.error);
    if (data.success) alert("Success: " + data.success);
}, "json");
```

You may want to handle the response differently but that should give you an idea.

Comment: thanks a lot,it works as u said,but when I use $.ajax(),it return undefined as data.success.Can u explain what is wrong?It will be helpful for me or you can share a link how jquery ajax call works in zend.Thanks in advance :)

Comment: got the solution i was passing data in wrong format,it should be  data:{"id":id}, and it works :).Thanks